# Does the Chromecast client honor Cache-Control or Expires headers?

Tags: chromecast

We are trying to setup CDN caching for the Receiver application and want to know if we can send the cache-control or expires headers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should honor those, either as pragma or header. If you run into a case that it doesn't, please drop us a line at chromecast-updates@google.com so to open a ticket.